# Number of integral solutions of polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

> Consider the equation $f(x) = x^4-ax^3-bx^2-cx-d=0,$ $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z^+,$ $ a≥b≥c≥d$ then number of integral solutions can be.

I am unable to use Integral Root theorem and just reached to the conclusion that if $\alpha$ is positive root of$f(x)$ then $\alpha >a$, nothing else. How should it be done?

Comment: What is $I^+$?${}$

Comment: Positive integer

Comment: That's usually denoted $\mathbb Z^+$, $\mathbb N$, $\mathbb Z_{>0}$ or some variant of those.

Comment: you cannot have negative integral roots since $-ax^3-bx^2 \ge 0, a \ge b >0, x \le -1$ and obviously you have one and only one positive real root which may be integral of course

Comment: @Conrad I didn't get it

Comment: Change $x<0$ to $-y, y>0$ and check that the polynomial in $y$ cannot have a solution greater or equal than $1$ hence, it cannot have an integral positive solution, hence the original polynomial cannot have a negative integral solution. The other point about the unicity of a real positive solution (existence trivial as $P(0)<0$) is general for polynomials of the given type $x^n-Q(x),Q$ lower degree and all non-negative coefficients and a positive free term - it's a good exercise but I can make it an answer if needed

Comment: @Conrad if $x > 0$,  $d = x(x^3 - ax^2 - bx- c)$ will it imply $d≥x ?$

Comment: in the integral case yes as $x^3-ax^2-bx-c \ge 1$ since it cannot be zero and it is positive as $d,x$ are; in the general real case, the reciprocal polynomial (which is here $-1$) $dx^4+cx^3+bx^2+ax-1$ has the same number of positive roots as the original one and it is obviously increasing (hence injective, so one root only) for $x>0$ as the derivative is positive

Comment: @Conrad I did it in this way, suggest a better way if you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1

Let $x ≥ 1$ be an integral root of $f(x)$
$\implies d = x(x^3 - ax^2 - bx - c)$
$\implies d≥x$

Also

$x^3(x - a) = bx^2+ cx + d$
$\implies x > a$

That's a contradiction as $a≥d$

Case 2

Let $x ≤ -1$

Put $x = -y$

$y^4 + ay^3 - by^2+ cy - d = y^4+y^2(ay - b) + cn - d > 0$

Thus $f(x)$ has no integral roots.